# Delete Item from CollectionView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to delete the second Item from a CollectionView. I use this line of code

```
self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem:1, inSection:0)])
```

I got this error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (31) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (31), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: You need to delete the objects IN your dataSource (whether its an NSArray or a NSDictionary), and then perform the `collection. deleteItemsAtIndexPaths()`. The issue, is that now, `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and/or `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` returns wrong info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that the line you have supplied is not incorrect on its own. It is the context you have placed it in that is the problem. Since you haven't given any context I'm going to assume it's because you have not first updated the data source for the collection view to reflect what you want in the view itself. That is, you must first delete the item from the data source and then delete it from the view.

Comment: And if I just delete the item from the data source and than reload the data why shall I call deleteItemsAtIndexPaths? This will not delete it from the view ?

Comment: If you delete from the data source and then call the `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` method it will perform a nice animation. Otherwise if you just reload data it will appear as if the deleted item just disappears.